# Allowing only specific section to scroll in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableview in which there are various section with variant number of rows in it... i just want specific section to scroll, rest remain in there position. i have no idea how to do this. can any help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in an `UITableView`.

If you need to design such a thing, put the *non scrollable section* on top the `UITableView` as a separate `View`.

This work similar to what you are trying to design.